# Overwrite value in document.cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, ab-testing, google-optimize

I'm running an AB test using Google 360 and I want switch variants in my browser.

I can do this by updating a the value of cookie `_gaexp` in my browser.  For example, this would look like:

"_gaexp: VARIANT_0"`.

If I use the EditThisCookie chrome extension and change the value to `VARIANT_0` and refresh my browser, I can see my Variant 0 text in my browser.

However, I want to update this dynamically via JavaScript, (for example, let's say on click).

Looking through console, I can see I have access to `document.cookie`, which contains the following cookings:

`"_gaexp=VARIANT_0; _ga=EXAMPLE_B; _gid=EXAMPLE_C"`

If I try and update `_gaexp` via console to VARIANT_1, my cookie doesn't update.  This is what I'm trying:

```
document.cookie = "_gaexp=VARIANT_1";
document.cookie;
"_gaexp=VARIANT_0; _ga=EXAMPLE_B; _gid=EXAMPLE_C, _gaexp=VARIANT_1"
```

It seems I'm adding a duplicate cookie by the same name, but I just want to:

- Replace this cooking via console using JavaScript.
- And then eventually, I would write addition JS to refresh the browser, (with the cookie updated).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I figured it out!

Just need to change the time stamps, to remove them:

```
// Delete
document.cookie = '_gaexp=VARIANT_0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/; domain=.mysite.co.uk'

// Add
document.cookie = '_gaexp=VARIANT_1; expires=Fri, 19 Jun 2020 20:47:11 UTC; path=/; domain=.mysite.co.uk'
```